# Connecting to SQL from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have built a C# Project with SQL Server database
The connection string is

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\GadoLab\GadoLab.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

I have put it on another computer for testing yesterday with SQL Express installed and put the program on the specified path as connection string but the program when i open it tells me that it can't connect to the database.

I also noticed that the SQL agent service isn't running and I can`t start it
what's the solution please?
The SQL Authentication mode is windows type

Comment: what is exact error text?

Comment: I don`t remember it exactly but it was like it can`t connect to the database for this server or please install sql server express

Comment: The SQL agent service cannot be started on the express version. This is because the agent is used to execute scheduled jobs and SQL Server Express does not support these. The lack of a running SQL Server agent isn't the cause of your connection issues. You need to post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: you should put your server name on `Data Source` , > eg . (Data Source=yourServerName;)

Comment: i want the database work on any server ignoring what it name is

Answer (score 5):

Few reasons of connection failures:

> ```
> 1. Wrong Connection String.
>
> 2. Lack of database existance.(Database does not exists)
>
> 3. Login Problems to database. (Wrong ID and password to database authentication)
>
> 4. Database is present on remote server and server is turned off.
> ```

There can be many more, but which one to apply in your case depends upon your code and exact situation of database.

Comment: if login id password is present then mention it in connection string properly.

Comment: no passowrd is present i make the sql with Windows authentication